# How do I use C# REST API HttpClient for both Basic header authentication and for default AD credentials?

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, active-directory, basic-authentication

This code results in a bad request or "A task was canceled." because it contains both type of authentication.

1. `handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`
2. `AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));`

```
//Create the HttpClientHandler
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

//Add the AD Credentials
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
if (Client == null)
{
    Client = new HttpClient(handler);

    Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5);

}

Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

//Add Basic header credentials for the remote server
var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}");
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));


if (ReqHeaders.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ReqHeaders)
    {
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

I need to first authenticate locally to the ESB and then to a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the Authorization header using `Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization`, try just setting the header directly:

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(authToken)}");
```

And are you sure the token should be in base 64 format?

Comment: This also worked for me :Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Service-Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));